# How do I flatten a Spark struct field into multiple rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've come across documentation and other pages that ask about flattening Spark structs into the same row, but I've been trying to flatten the data into different rows. Say we have the following data:

| ID | struct_field |
| --- | --- |
| 3333 | [{"code": 123, "description": "Business Email"}, {"code": 789, "description": "Primary Email"}] |
| 9234 | [{"code": 123, "description": "Business Email"}, {"code": 789, "description": "Primary Email"}, {"code": 456, "description": "Secondary Email"}] |

And I want it in this format:

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 3333 | Business Email |
| 3333 | Primary Email |
| 9234 | Business Email |
| 9234 | Primary Email |
| 9234 | Secondary Email |

I've been trying a variety of solutions but haven't been able to get anywhere with doing this all in PySpark.

Comment: Can you do .printSchema() on your dataframe and add the result here,